# overlaping More than 2 html elements

Tags: html, css

I know the property : z-index sorts the elemenets that have overlaping and The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element (which element should be placed in front of, or behind, the others). But when we have 3 elements what shal we do ? For example:

```
<div id="1"> 
    <div id="2"> 
        <div id="3"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

If you want to Put  The most forward and after that  and after that  what should i do ?

I dont have any problems with 2 overlaped element and can put them in order but 3element is confusing and i lose my div :(

like this : [example image](http://www.xum.ir/images/2014/01/24/Untitled-1rOHwi.jpg)

Comment: use the same property  z-index to order them

Comment: the example image you linked to shows the divs in the default order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can have as many `z-index` as you need.
You could have:

```
z-index   -9999
z-index     0
z-index    9999
```

Look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cristian_cena/xY5Re/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use z-index if the divs are located inside of eachother.  I think you are looking for something like this.  You need to change the sizes, colors and postions to put everything where you want it, but here is what you posted in your example.

```
 <div id="1" style="height:373px; width:416px; background-color:#CCFF00; top:65px; left:54px; position:relative"> 
   <div id="2" style="height:279px; width:295px; background-color:#EA4800; top:65px; left:92px; position:relative">
     <div id="3" style="height:156px; width:180px; background-color:#00C1EA; top:91px; left:38px; position:relative">         
     </div> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

If you want to have divs that are not inside of each other then you will need to use z-index"#".  Then you should do something like this:

```
 <div id="1" style="height:373px; width:416px; background-color:#CCFF00; top:65px; left:54px; position:absolute; z-index:0"></div> 
 <div id="2" style="height:279px; width:295px; background-color:#EA4800; top:130px; left:146px; position:absolute; z-index:10"></div> 
 <div id="3" style="height:156px; width:180px; background-color:#00C1EA; top:221px; left:184px; position:absolute; z-index:20"></div>
```